# Make dynamic layout Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fluid-layout

How can I achieve this effect using Swing:
[image]

When resizing of the width the `JFrame`, I want the blue `JPanel` to be fluid and the green `JPanel` to be fixed. When resizing the height, I want both to be fixed. I also want the blue `JPanel` to not have less than some predefined width and the green `JPanel` to never move under the blue `JPanel`, remaining always on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MigLayout was designed for these situations:
http://www.miglayout.com/

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout(
    "", 
    "[grow][200px]", // Column constraints
    "[100px]"        // Row constraints
));
```